# Расстановка ударений

Tags: орфоэпия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли расставил ударения?

> ЗИна и ЛЮда живУт в дерЕвне. К ним в сад чАсто прилетАют синИцы.
>   ДЕвочки сдЕлали кормУшку и повЕсили ее на дЕрево.
>   ТепЕрь птИцам морОз не стрАшен.

Comment: В каком месте сомнения? И Вас над Ё ставить ударения не учили?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, вероятно,  речь идет о фразовых (тонических) ударениях, которые выделяются голосом при чтении текста:

Зина и ЛЮда // живут в дерЕвне. К ним в сАд //часто прилетют синИцы. Девочки сделали кормУшку //и повесили ее на дЕрево. ТепЕрь птицам //мороз не стрАшен.

Примечание

Вероятно, это задание для младших школьников, но ответ дан просто для правильного прочтения текста, также дополнительно обозначены паузы.

Повествовательный текст состоит из простых предложений небольшого объема, которые делятся паузой на две части, а ударение ставится в конце каждой части (фразы).

Только в последнем (заключительном) предложении ударение смещено на первое (более значащее) слово - это логическое ударение. Такое смещение важно, так как  подчеркивается общая идея сказанного.

Comment: Это задание из учебника 2 класса. Спасибо за коммент, но просто скажите, правильно ли расставлены ударения?

Comment: Если это ударения в отдельных словах, а не в тексте, то правильно.